# Calculus based or calculus-based?

Tags: definition, article-writing

I've noticed something strange in the literature. Regardless of context, there seems to be a trend where some authors will say 'calculus-based solution' or 'calculus-based physics' whereas others will not use the hyphen and say something like 'calculus based bound'. In my own writing, I've usually stuck to avoiding the hyphen, however I'm starting to have my doubts. Is one of these choices always correct? Or is there a relevant set of rules of grammar?

Comment: You may find this link useful https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp

Comment: @caverac If I'm reading that right, it's saying to always use the hyphen for calculus-based (suffix rule 1)?

Comment: Correct! Because calculus-based serves here as an adjective, e.g. calculus-based solution

Answer (score 0):

Solved by caverac's link in the comments. https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp suffix rule 1. Use the hyphen always.

Comment: I wouldn’t say “always.” When a noun phrase is used _attributively_, then it should be hyphenated. However, when it’s the predicate of a copula (“X is Y”), then, as the linked document points out, it depends on the specific phrase.